# How to check the divisor for 0 in a C program generating random expressions?

Tags: c, string, expression, bnf

I am trying to write a C program to generate random elementary arithmetic expressions. All operands should be unsigned integers, and every intermediate calculation result should be truncated to 32 bits.

Here is how I implement it. I generate an expression according to its BNF:

> <expr> ::= <number>
>  | "(" <expr> ")"
>  | <expr> "+" <expr>
>  | <expr> "-" <expr>
>  | <expr> "*" <expr>
>  | <expr> "/" <expr>

Then I put the expression into the `buf` string.

However, the problem is, this may generate an expression divided by 0. Currently the only solution I can think of is to calculate the divisor. But the random expression is a **character string**. Is there any better way to generate valid expressions?

Here is my code to generate random expressions.

```
// this should be enough
static char buf[65536];
static inline void gen_rand_expr() {
    // memset(buf, 0, 65536);
    // char temp[65536];
    char *tmp = NULL;
    switch ((int)((double)rand() / ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1) * 3)) {
    case 0:
        sprintf(buf, "%u", (uint32_t)((double)rand() / ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1) * UINT32_MAX));
        break;
    case 1:
        gen_rand_expr();
        if (strlen(buf) > 65441) break;
        tmp = strdup(buf);
        strcpy(buf, "(");
        strcat(buf, tmp);
        strcat(buf, ")");
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        break;
    default:
        gen_rand_expr();
        tmp = strdup(buf);
        gen_rand_expr();
        switch ((int)((double)rand() / ((uint64_t)RAND_MAX + 1) * 4)) {
        case 0:
            if (strlen(buf) + strlen(tmp) > 65440) break;
            strcat(buf, " + ");
            strcat(buf, tmp);
            break;
        case 1:
            if (strlen(buf) + strlen(tmp) > 65440) break;
            strcat(buf, " - ");
            strcat(buf, tmp);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (strlen(buf) + strlen(tmp) > 65440) break;
            strcat(buf, " * ");
            strcat(buf, tmp);
            break;
        default:
            if (strlen(buf) + strlen(tmp) > 65440) break;
            strcat(buf, " / ");
            strcat(buf, tmp);
            break;
        }
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: One important point is that calculation of divisors is not so trivial. For example, the divisor in the first `/` of this expression `1/((((65536*65536)+1)/1)-1)` will become zero if the intermediate calculation result is truncated to fit into `uint32_t`, but it is not zero when no truncation happens.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, but in this case, the intermediate result will be truncated. So, we can just consider the first situation and see it as a division by zero exception.

Comment: Maybe generate expressions in [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)? You still have to calculate the divisor(s) but at least you can avoid recursion ...